# My android app is blocked by other

Tags: android

Another app (more popular than my) won't starts if my app is installed, it uses

```
 private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```

It receives the package name from network, I think I can create a VPN service with packet filtering, but it's no better solution. 
Maybe a better solution exists?

Comment: Why do you care if somebody other developer put in code in their app so that app does not run if your app is installed? The decision of whether or not to run is up to the other developer, not you.

Comment: A lot of users use the app (taxi driver software), they can't try our app )